# Question about linear and quadratic convergence.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Linear convergence is defined:

> Suppose that the sequence $\{x_k \}$ converges to the number $L$. We say that this sequence converges linearly to $L$, if $\exists$ a number $\mu \in (0, 1)$, such that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_{k} - L|} = \mu$$

and quadratic convergence is defined as

> $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1} - L|}{|x_{k} - L|^2} = \mu$$

> where $\mu > 0$.

What would happen if for linear convergence I get $\mu$ $\notin (0,1)$. What would this imply? Why is the denominator for quadratic convergence squared?

Comment: You cannot get $\mu \notin (0,1)$ for linear convergence, because that would not be linear convergence, by the definition. If $\mu =0$ that is called super-linear, and if $\mu =1$ that is called sub-linear.

Comment: Although "quad" typically means four, since "quadratum" means square in Latin (a square has four sides), a second order polynomial is called a quadratic equation. That's why convergence with the denominator squared is called quadratic convergence.

Comment: @BintEuler Keep in mind that it only makes senes to analyse the speed of convergence if the sequence actually converges. In the case of linear convergence, if we had $\mu>1$, the sequence terms would be drifting away from $L$, not converging to $L$.